# AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup cell color

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How to specify the color of the text inside a particular cell contained in AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup in Flex? The code is in action script and the text color varies according to the value that the cell contains. i.e. if it is negative value it has to be displayed in red otherwise black.

Please mention if there is any work around too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done example with functionality that you describe. Hope, it will help.

```
        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="grid"
                             itemRenderer="MyAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer"
                             dataProvider="{dataProvider}"
                             width="200" height="100%">

            <mx:groupedColumns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="name"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="score"/>
            </mx:groupedColumns>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

        <mx:Script>  
            <![CDATA[  
                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

                [Bindable]  
                private var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([  
                    {name:"Name1", score:-12},   
                    {name:"Name2", score:10},   
                    {name:"Name3", score:-100},   
                ]);
            ]]>  
        </mx:Script> 
    </mx:Application>
```

And class MyAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer.as:

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer;
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridListData;

    public class MyAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer
    {

        public function MyAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function validateProperties():void
        {
            super.validateProperties();
            if (listData)
            {
                var item:Object = AdvancedDataGridListData(listData).item;
                if (AdvancedDataGridListData(listData).dataField == "score") {
                    setStyle("color", item.score < 0 ? 0xff0000 : 0x000000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```